# Sending notification to specific device using Azure Notification Hub (Test Send)

Tags: azure, firebase-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

I'm trying to send a notification to my Android device using Azure Notification Hub.

When I use the Test Send functionality which is available in Azure Notification Hub it doesn't seem to care about the property "to" in the payload. 
For example if I specify a fake deviceId like below I still receive a notification on my device.

```
{
"to" : "fW4Xab4JY3F:ERT91bHC4_hqzGj4AaHB_u1Dvzai6hFxyHFscgQ_TRAqWD1JGsE7FqFmknSuwlCEImmyn9R1gCDpsObZk33mpqaqdhWC_712AW2PI47ni15Jyrwq12xcSs9tZ784sLabz2I64J2LSe4q",
"notification": {
"title": "TITel",
"body": "Firebase Cloud Message"
  }
}
```

If I [do the same using Postman](https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send) and calls the server side API of FCM I get a response saying InvalidRegistration if I enter a fake `deviceId`. And if I use a correct deviceId I get the notification as expected.

Anyone knows why the payload isn't working as I would expect it to within Azure Notification Hub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test Send is for testing only. The way it works is it sends notifications to 10 random devices. I guess the reason why it works for you from NH is probably because you have a few devices (or maybe even just 1 device) so all of them get notifications.

The reason why it doesn't work with FCM is because, as you mentioned, this is a fake ID. If you use an existing one, it should work.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for spending time on this. Then I know I can't trust the Test Send functionality. However, when I try to send the notification using the method SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync(string jsonPayload) it seems that NH doesn't care what's in the to-property. My device still receives every notification.

Comment: It's not that you can't trust it, it's just that it was designed for a different purpose. For what it seems like you're doing, you don't need a test send. If you know exactly which device you want to test it on, just push directly to that device in regular mode.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again Nikita. Yes I know exactly the device I want to send to. What do you mean by push directly to the device in regular mode? Do you mean that I should use the Direct Send feature available in the Standard Tier of NH? We currently run on the Free Tier.

Comment: Register a device with a unique tag (like a used id or email) and then push to that tag that you know is assigned to only a single user. And make sure that it's not a test send.

Comment: Thanks Nikita. Figured it out!